# copy from local Arraylist to global ArrayList in android

Tags: android

**I have a method like this it just splits the image into few chunks**

```
public void splitImage(Bitmap bmp, int chunks, int imageCode) {

        int chunkHeight, chunkWidth;
        int rows, cols;
        rows = cols = 5;

        //To store all the small image chunks in bitmap format in this list 
        ArrayList<Bitmap> greyImageChunks = new ArrayList<Bitmap>(chunks);
        ArrayList<Bitmap> greenImageChunks = new ArrayList<Bitmap>(chunks);
        ArrayList<Bitmap> redImageChunks = new ArrayList<Bitmap>(chunks);


        //Getting the scaled bitmap of the source image
        //BitmapDrawable drawable = (BitmapDrawable) image.getDrawable();
        //Bitmap bitmap = drawable.getBitmap();
        Bitmap scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp, bmp.getWidth(), bmp.getHeight(), true);

        rows = cols = (int) Math.sqrt(chunks);
        chunkHeight = bmp.getHeight()/rows;
        chunkWidth = bmp.getWidth()/cols;

        //xCoord and yCoord are the pixel positions of the image chunks
        int yCoord = 0;
        for(int x=0; x<rows; x++){
            int xCoord = 0;
            for(int y=0; y<cols; y++){

                if(imageCode == 1) {
                    greyImageChunks.add(Bitmap.createBitmap(scaledBitmap, xCoord, yCoord, chunkWidth, chunkHeight));    
                } else if(imageCode == 2) {
                    greenImageChunks.add(Bitmap.createBitmap(scaledBitmap, xCoord, yCoord, chunkWidth, chunkHeight));
                } else if(imageCode == 3) {    
                    redImageChunks.add(Bitmap.createBitmap(scaledBitmap, xCoord, yCoord, chunkWidth, chunkHeight));
                }

                xCoord += chunkWidth;
            }
            yCoord += chunkHeight;
        }
    }
```

Here I would like to retrieve chunks from the greyImageChunks, greenImageChunks and redImageChunks using another method say mergeImages().

These are not accessed by outside world because they are locally created.
Is there any method to access these array Lists outside of this method.
Can any copy method from one local ArrayList to another global ArrayList possible?
Please help me.

**Note: ArrayList size should be dynamic because the size of ArrayList is defined using int chunks in splitImage()  method**

Comment: You can create three  global variables and add those chunks to that variables in splitImage method.

Comment: Thanks Prashanth.. its working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i understood correctly, Create one Global `ArrayList` say `mArrayList`.

```
ArrayList<Bitmap> mArrayList= new ArrayList<Bitmap>();
```

Now inside your method, after for loop add all three local ArrayLists to Global ArrayList.

```
for(int x=0; x<rows; x++){
        int xCoord = 0;
        for(int y=0; y<cols; y++){

            if(imageCode == 1) {
                greyImageChunks.add(Bitmap.createBitmap(scaledBitmap, xCoord, yCoord, chunkWidth, chunkHeight));    
            } else if(imageCode == 2) {
                greenImageChunks.add(Bitmap.createBitmap(scaledBitmap, xCoord, yCoord, chunkWidth, chunkHeight));
            } else if(imageCode == 3) {    
                redImageChunks.add(Bitmap.createBitmap(scaledBitmap, xCoord, yCoord, chunkWidth, chunkHeight));
            }

            xCoord += chunkWidth;
        }
        yCoord += chunkHeight;
    }
mArrayList.addAll(greyImageChunks);
mArrayList.addAll(greenImageChunks);
mArrayList.addAll(redImageChunks);
```

Comment: HI Vrund.. Thanks for the answer. Its working. Accepting it as answer (thumbsup)

Comment: Happy to help... :)

Answer (score 1):

Use array instead of ArrayList for imagechunks and make your `splitImage()` method return Arraylist of arrays of bitmaps?
Something like this:

`return ArrayList<Bitmap[]> chunksArray;`

EDIT:

```
public ArrayList<Bitmap[]> splitImage(Bitmap bmp, int chunks, int imageCode){
    int chunkHeight, chunkWidth;
    int rows, cols;
    rows = cols = 5;

    //To store all the small image chunks in bitmap format in this list
   // ArrayList<Bitmap> greyImageChunks = new ArrayList<Bitmap>(chunks);
    //ArrayList<Bitmap> greenImageChunks = new ArrayList<Bitmap>(chunks);
   // ArrayList<Bitmap> redImageChunks = new ArrayList<Bitmap>(chunks);
    Bitmap [] greyImageChunks = new Bitmap[chunks];
    Bitmap [] greenImageChunks = new Bitmap[chunks];
    Bitmap [] redImageChunks = new Bitmap[chunks];

    ArrayList< Bitmap[]> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();



    //Getting the scaled bitmap of the source image
    //BitmapDrawable drawable = (BitmapDrawable) image.getDrawable();
    //Bitmap bitmap = drawable.getBitmap();
    Bitmap scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp, bmp.getWidth(), bmp.getHeight(), true);

    rows = cols = (int) Math.sqrt(chunks);
    chunkHeight = bmp.getHeight()/rows;
    chunkWidth = bmp.getWidth()/cols;

    //xCoord and yCoord are the pixel positions of the image chunks
    int yCoord = 0, greyCount=0, greenCount=0, redCount=0;
    for(int x=0; x<rows; x++){
        int xCoord = 0;
        for(int y=0; y<cols; y++){

            if(imageCode == 1) {
                greyImageChunks[greyCount]= Bitmap.createBitmap(scaledBitmap, xCoord, yCoord, chunkWidth, chunkHeight);
                greyCount++;
            } else if(imageCode == 2) {
                greenImageChunks[greenCount]= Bitmap.createBitmap(scaledBitmap, xCoord, yCoord, chunkWidth, chunkHeight);
                greenCount++;
            } else if(imageCode == 3) {
                redImageChunks[redCount]= Bitmap.createBitmap(scaledBitmap, xCoord, yCoord, chunkWidth, chunkHeight);
                redCount++;
            }

            xCoord += chunkWidth;
        }
        yCoord += chunkHeight;
    }
    arrayList.add(greyImageChunks);
    arrayList.add(greenImageChunks);
    arrayList.add(redImageChunks);


    return arrayList;

}
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate it.

Comment: Accepted answer adds all chunks to same arrayList. Is this what you wanted?

Comment: Yes, In accepted answer it adds all chunks to same list. But here am creating different arrays for three colors. But basic copy is same right?

Comment: Coming to your answer, It is looking precise but how Can I retrieve only green, only red, only gray images in another method?? 
Sorry am really new to android so asking this..

Comment: In your method where you call `splitImage(Bitmap bmp, int chunks, int imageCode)` . `ArrayList< Bitmap[]> chunksList = splitImage(Bitmap bmp, int chunks, int imageCode);` First element off `chunksList` is going to be grey, second green and third red .

Comment: Ok. But How can I retrieve only gray image chunks??
I mean How can I refer gray image chunk 1 2 3 ...

Comment: First element of `chunksList` element is `Bitmap [] greyImageChunks`. You can retreive it by getting first element of list. Example :`Bitmap [] greyImageChunks = chunksList.get(0);`

Comment: I got it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Happy to be helpful.